# Adding a reference to an xml schema to XML Serialized Output

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

When serializing object with the code:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
using (var xmlWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myTypeInstance);
}
```

In the output xml file I get:

```
<MyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

How do I add a reference to xml schema to it, so it looks like this:

```
<MyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Edit]

You could implement IXmlSerializable explicitly and write/read the xml yourself.

```
public class MyType : IXmlSerializable
{
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace, "mySchema.xsd");

        // other elements & attributes
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myTypeInstance);
```

Most likely not an ideal solution but adding the following field and attribute to your class will do the trick.

```
public class MyType
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Schema = @"mySchema.xsd";
}
```

Another option is the create your own custom XmlTextWriter class.

```
xmlSerializer.Serialize(new CustomXmlTextWriter(xmlWriter), myTypeInstance);
```

Or don't use Serialization

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

var xmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("MyType");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlNode);

xmlNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

var schema = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
schema.Value = "mySchema.xsd";
xmlNode.SetAttributeNode(schema);

xmlDoc.Save(...);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Note that one could make use of the  `XmlSchema.Namespace` and `XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace` constants here.