# How to Change xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute prefix name to xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation using XmlSerializerNamespaces

Tags: c#, xml

Using XmlSerializerNamespaces I'm adding the namespace for xml whereas I want this particular namespace should be **xsi:**noNamespaceSchemaLocation:"http://.." instead it automatically taking as  xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation:http://.."

C#

```
var namesp = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namesp.Add("dc", "http://www.example/1.1/");
namesp.Add("noNamespaceSchemaLocation","http://www.sample/1.1/e.xsd);
```

Expected XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ssv xmlns:dc="http://www.example/1.1/" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.sample/1.1/e.xsd">
```

O/p Getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ssv xmlns:dc="http://www.example/1.1/" xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.sample/1.1/e.xsd">
```

Is there any way to change the prefix of namespace?

Please Help!

Comment: How are you generating your XML?  Directly using `XmlWriter`?  Via LINQ to XML?  Via `XmlDocument`?  Or serializing using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` isn't an XML namespace declaration.   It's a regular XML attribute, specifically a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#xsi_schemaLocation) that *provide[s] hints as to the physical location of schema documents which can be used for ·assessment·*  You can't use `XmlSerializerNamespaces` to add non-namespace attributes, you will need to use a different approach to emit the attribute.

Comment: For instance, if you are using `XmlSerializer`, see [Adding a reference to an xml schema to XML Serialized Output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609462/3744182).  For `XmlDocument` see [How do I add a namespace when creating an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932535/3744182).  For `XmlWriter` see [how to add xml namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/928240/3744182).